# unable to connect using SSH2

Tags: php, ssh

I am using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html) in my project. I have installed it and am testing it using the following piece of code which is similar to the example [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html).

**Updated Code:**

```
1           require("Net/SSH2.php");
2   
3           if (!class_exists('Net_SSH2')) die("Class Net_SSH2 doesn't exist!");
4           
5           $ssh = new Net_SSH2('***');   // the host IP address 
6           
7           if (!method_exists($ssh, 'Net_SSH2')) die("Net_SSH2 class doesn't have Net_SSH2 method!");
8    
9           if (!$ssh->login('***', '***')) {   // (verified) username and password
10              echo "LOG: " . $ssh->getLog() . "<br>";
11              exit('Login failed!');
12          }
```

**Code Update 2:**

```
1       require("Net/SSH2.php");
2
3       define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);
4
5       if (!class_exists('Net_SSH2')) die("Class Net_SSH2 doesn't exist!");
6       
7       $ssh = new Net_SSH2('***');   // the host IP address 
8       
9       if (!method_exists($ssh, 'Net_SSH2')) die("Net_SSH2 class doesn't have Net_SSH2 method!");
10
11      if (!$ssh->login('***', '***')) {   // (verified) username and password
12          echo "LOG: " . $ssh->getLog() . "<br>";
13          echo "ALL ERRORS: ";
14          print_r($ssh->getErrors());
15          echo "<br>LAST ERROR: " . $ssh->getLastError() . "<br>";
16          exit('Login failed!');
17      }
```

It exits at line # 16. `getLog()` gives nothing so it is hard to know where the problem is. I had the login credentials tested using PuTTY. It is not able to login to other servers either. I am not able to understand *what* is causing the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: At the very first line put `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` and you'll be able to see output of `$ssh->getLog()`

Comment: I tried that. It did not show anything for $ssh->getLog()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hosting my code on the server (server B) that I was trying to connect. The same code worked in the opposite direction (I could connect to the server A where my code previously was)! I ended up concluding that the server A has environmental issues.
I appreciate those were helping me here!

Answer (score 1):

`Net_SSH2` is not a function, this is a class and constructor within this class.
So 3rd line should be

```
if (!class_exists('Net_SSH2')) die("Class Net_SSH2 doesn't exist!");
```

If you wanna check further if `Net_SSH2` method exists in class `Net_SSH2` after line 5 you can add this:

```
if (!method_exists($ssh, 'Net_SSH2')) die("Net_SSH2 class doesn't have Net_SSH2 method");
```

Comment: I did the modifications as you said. Now it is exiting at line 8. The login credentials are correct though.

Comment: @rad so my modifications are working fine. Its hard to say what can be with wrong line 8. Double check your credentials, maybe something wrong with server you're trying to connect etc

Comment: Yes, it is working till that part. However, the credentials are correct, I just checked in using PuTTY. I also tried connecting to different server but the login failed again.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit the "Enable Logging" button on the link you provided you'll see that the following is done right after Net/SSH2.php is included:

```
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);
```

Try that.

Comment: I had tried that, it dint make any difference. Sorry. Please refer to my updated code.

Comment: What does var_dump($ssh->getLog()) say?

Comment: My guess is that you're somehow suppressing E_USER_NOTICE errors and that you're not connecting to the SSH server at all.  Maybe there's some setting in your php.ini that's doing it.  Anyway try this: http://pastebin.com/SuSPQANC

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this at the top of your PHP script:

```
error_reporting(E_USER_NOTICE);
```

Setting error_reporting to 0 suppresses user_error so it's quite possible your PHP setup is just suppressing the error.  eg.

```
error_reporting(E_USER_NOTICE);

user_error('zzzz', E_USER_NOTICE);
```

vs.

```
error_reporting(0);

user_error('zzzz', E_USER_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could change your line 3 to:

```
if( !class_exists('Net_SSH2')...
```

But I would suggest you throw in some Exception handling. When using the PHPSecLib, I had nothing but issues, so I created [this SSH2 Class](http://www.highonphp.com/php-ssh2-class-with-exception-handling) which does require the PHP SSH2 Extension to be installed.

You should try calling: `getLog()` to find out why it's failing.

```
echo $ssh->getLog();
```

Comment: Its not about the path. If I echo something from SSH2.php, I can actually see it on the webpage.

Comment: I had the SSH2 class appended inside SSH2.php and then I tried the 'SSH2 Usage' part from that link you provided, but it fails at line 17 in it. It is not able to connect to the server. Also, echo $ssh->getLog(); gives nothing. Sorry.

Comment: In that class, it is actually using the function ssh2_connect(), I dont have it installed because I found that phpseclib is better but its not working for me.

Comment: Did you connect from Putty on the same machine that is trying to access the box? Are there any ACL's on the server you are trying to SSH into?

Comment: Yes, I connected from PuTTY on the same machine. How do I check the ACL's on that server?

Answer (score 0):

Given the latest comments, I assume your code exists at line 8 (where the Net_SSH2() object is instantiated)...

I just had a very similar issue where, once deployed, `include()` would work but `check_exists()` and instantiating a new `Net_SSH2` object would fail... But parsing my php file (before deployment) with the php command line tool would work fine...

**So the problem was on the server (Apache in my case): the directory where phpseclib was installed had permissions set so that I could not even `cd` to it.**

As it happened, my hoem made deploying script was simply copying the files on the server and setting odd permissions so that the SSH2.php was not accessible.

Perhaps you have a similar problem here?